# Appending values based on the number of occurrences in a list

Tags: python

Currently, i have a list containing:

```
table = [[3, 'AVENGERS',PACIFIC'],[1, 'A WALK,DRAGONBALL'],[2, 'A WALK,DRAGONBALL'],[5, 'A WALK,DRAGONBALL'],[6, 'JAMES BOND,MISSION'],[7,'JAMES BOND,MISSION']]
```

and I'm writing a program **to extract the numeric value** from each list within the table, if the **string element is found in other lists too.**

For example, the string **'A WALK,DRAGONBALL'** is found in **list 2,3 and 4** and the string **'JAMES BOND,MISSION'** is found in **list 5 and 6** respectively. For every similar occurrences, i want to **extract the numeric value at index 0** and append into a list.

For 'A WALK,DRAGONBALL' and 'JAMES BOND,MISSION' i will append:

```
movieName = ['A WALK,DRAGONBALL','JAMES BOND,MISSION']
movieNum = [[1,2,5],[6,7]]
```

where in the list movieNum, the first list represents the number for 'A WALK,DRAGONBALL' and the second list for 'JAMES BOND,MISSION'. Here's what I did:

```
movie = []
movieNum = []
movielst = []

for i in range(len(table)-1):
    if table[i][1] == table[i+1][1]:
        movie.append(table[i][1])
        movieNum.append([table[i][0],table[i+1][0]])
print(movieNum)

for i in movie:
    if i not in movielst:
        movielst.append(i)

print(movielst)
```

I was able to print out the movielst correctly but I'm having issue with the **movieNum** list as instead of getting a **list of non duplicates**,

```
[[1,2,5],[6,7]]
```

I'm getting:

```
[[1,2],[2,5],[6,7]]
```

What should i do in order to resolve the duplicate number?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` for this.

```
from collections import defaultdict

table = [[3, 'AVENGERS','PACIFIC'],[1, 'A WALK,DRAGONBALL'],[2, 'A WALK,DRAGONBALL'],
         [5, 'A WALK,DRAGONBALL'],[6, 'JAMES BOND,MISSION'],[7,'JAMES BOND,MISSION']]

d = defaultdict(list)

for num, *movies in table:
    for movie in movies:
        d[movie].append(num)

d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if len(v)>1}
```

**Result**

```
{'A WALK,DRAGONBALL': [1, 2, 5], 'JAMES BOND,MISSION': [6, 7]}
```

You can extract keys and values for the result dictionary:

```
keys, values = d.keys(), d.values()

# dict_keys(['A WALK,DRAGONBALL', 'JAMES BOND,MISSION'])
# dict_values([[1, 2, 5], [6, 7]])
```

Comment: is there any method other than using dict data structure? am i able to achieve the output with only loops?

Comment: Yes, look at @Ajax1234's solution. Although you should not have any inherent bias between using `for` loops and `dict`. Choose what makes most sense for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
table = [[3, 'AVENGERS','PACIFIC'],[1, 'A WALK,DRAGONBALL'],[2, 'A WALK,DRAGONBALL'],[5, 'A WALK,DRAGONBALL'],[6, 'JAMES BOND,MISSION'],[7,'JAMES BOND,MISSION']]
new_table = [list(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(table, key=lambda x:x[1:]), key=lambda x:x[1:])]
last_results = [[b for b, _ in i] for i in new_table if len(i) > 1]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 5], [6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do :

```
final_dict={}

table = [[3, 'AVENGERS PACIFIC'],[1, 'A WALK,DRAGONBALL'],[2, 'A WALK,DRAGONBALL'],[5, 'A WALK,DRAGONBALL'],[6, 'JAMES BOND,MISSION'],[7,'JAMES BOND,MISSION']]


for i in table:
    if i[1] not in final_dict:
        final_dict[i[1]] = [i[0]]
    else:
        final_dict[i[1]].append(i[0])
print({i:j for i,j in final_dict.items() if len(j)>1})
```

output:

```
{'A WALK,DRAGONBALL': [1, 2, 5], 'JAMES BOND,MISSION': [6, 7]}
```

if you want only names then:

```
print(list(filter(lambda x:len(final_dict[x])>1,final_dict.keys())))
```